# Writing unit test cases for flask application

Tags: python, flask

I'm making a web application using flask framework. To display a web page using flask, I use a **render_template()** function.
For example:

```
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/')
def restaurantMenu(restaurant_id):
    try:
        # pdb.set_trace()
        session = get_session()
        restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
        if restaurant is not None:
            menu_items = session.query(MenuItem).filter(
                  MenuItem.restaurant_id == restaurant.id
            )
        session.close()
        if menu_items is not None:
            return render_template('menu.html', restaurant=restaurant, items=menu_items)
    except NoResultFound:
        return render_template('error.html', error_message='No such restaurant id.')
```

And

```
@app.route('/')
def welcomePage():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

How do I write test cases for functions like these? I'm new to testing so I wanted to write test cases for my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test app in your tests and call it very simply, like so:

```
app = create_app().test_client()
result = app.get('/')
assert('something' in result.data)
```

That gives you the general idea - it's pretty easy to work with.  More information can be found in the Flask Testing Docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/